How to use table alias in KQL query
I want to select some columns in multiple temporary table. So, I need to select columns with table alias in KQL.
Example in ANSI SQL:
Select a.col1,b.col2 from a inner join b on a.id = b.id

Example in KQL:
let TableA = external_table('table1')
| take 100
let TableB = external_table('table2')
| take 100 
TableA
| join kind=inner (TableB) on id
| project TableA.id,TableB.col2

I encountered an error as shown below:

How can I change the KQL query to resolve this error. Selecting multiple columns from multiple tables in KQL.

Have you tried this:
EDIT 1
let TableA = external_table('table1')
  | take 100
  | project TableAId = id, TableACol2 = col2;
let TableB = external_table('table2')
  | take 100
  | project TableBId = id, TableBCol2 = col2;
TableA
  | join kind=inner (TableB) on $left.TableAId == $right.TableBId
  | project TableAId, TableBId, TableACol2, TableBCol2

Here you are renaming the Id-Columns explicitly, to reuse them in the resulting JOIN.

Usually the common columns get different names like id2 and col22 or something like that. Than you can refer these new names.

I tried, but some column names are common to both tables. So I need to refer table name as well

As I said, column names which are common to both tables will be renamed like id2 etc. When you execute the query without the project line, than you can see these names and reference it. TableA.Id does not work.

@Rasith I´ve changed my post with a little bit more detail. Just project it the way I´ve showed in my post. Then you can reuse all projected column names.

Thank you for answering my question and supporting.
